# bash script to restart apache if apachectl passes

Tags: bash, apache

I'm working on a bash script that rewrites vhost files and then restarts apache to pick up the changes. It all works fine but I want to check the status of apachectl before restarting apache in case the vhost files have syntax errors.

I know how to run `apachectl -S` from the command line, but I want my script to work like:

```
if(apachectl passes){

   service httpd restart

}
```

I guess I could just parse the output and look for 'Syntax OK' but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
if apachectl -S; then
  service httpd restart
else
  // action if config parsing failed
fi
```

`apachectl` will result a non zero exit code, jumping to the `else` branch.

Comment: Awesome thats exactly what I needed! Thanks mate